# Can't get user id in TS file in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, compiler-errors

I can't get user id in TS file in Angular

> _id: undefined Http failure response for http://localhost:5000/users/undefined

Service File:

```js
UpdateUser(userID:any, data : any){
  return this.httpClient.put<User>(`${environment.APIURL}/users/${userID}`,JSON.stringify(data),this.options)
  .pipe(map((res:any)=>{
    return res
  }))
}
```

Comment: TS file:  userObj:User= new User()

Comment: Could you send your ts in file detail? so that it may help to give the solution.

Comment: Are you getting userID in the URL?

Comment: i think the problem in ts file who calling the `UpdateUser` in your service. if ou can write more detail to make this question useful and we can give some solution, thanks.

Comment: thank's the problem is solved, the problem was in User Model.ts